# bottom tabs how not to show name

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have app.js in which:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();


export default function App() {

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Tab.Navigator>
                <Tab.Screen name='Home' component={Home} />
            </Tab.Navigator >
        </NavigationContainer>
    )

}
```

I display the bottom tabs, but I see the navigation at the top that shows "Home" as with StackNavigator. I want there to be no true field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Hide bottom tab label:

```js
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();


export default function App() {

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Tab.Navigator
               tabBarOptions={{
                   showLabel: false, // add this line to hide tab label
     
                }}
               >
                <Tab.Screen name='Home' component={Home} />
            </Tab.Navigator >
        </NavigationContainer>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 3):

### 2023 Edit on [Anwar Gul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69153303/16870974)

Using `tabBarOptions` in your `<Tab.Navigator>` component still works but it throws the following message:

`WARN: Bottom Tab Navigator: 'tabBarOptions' is deprecated. Migrate the options to 'screenOptions' instead.`

Because `tabBarOptions` is **deprecated**, you should now use `screenOptions` instead.

This is what your provided code `app.js` would look like if you wanted to **hide the bottom tab's label**:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();


export default function App() {

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Tab.Navigator
                screenOptions={{ 
                    tabBarShowLabel: false,
                }}
            >
                <Tab.Screen name='Home' component={Home} />
            </Tab.Navigator >
        </NavigationContainer>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was necessary to add for tabs.screen

```
options = {{headerShown: false}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have to display null the label like as below. Add false to label in main tab navigator, so all pages remains same as not appearing the label.

add tabBarOptions={{showLabel: false}} in Tab.Navigator

```
<Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{showLabel: false}}>
```

Here is the official reference link: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

To hide the screen heading use the prop "headerShown" set the boolean value to this prop

To hide the Icon label use the prop tabBarShowLabel set the boolean value to this prop

both the properties should come under the screenOptions property for the Navigator`enter code here`

```
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    tabBarShowLabel: true,
    headerShown: false,
  }}>
  <Tab.Screen name="Screen 1" component={Scrn 1} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Screen 2" component={Scrn 2} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Screen 3" component={Scrn 3} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```